# EVENT_MOUSEMOVE not working while using with createTrackbar() method in OpenCV for making paint application?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have been trying to make a simple Paint application using `OpenCV` and Python.

Here I have used trackbar methods to create five `adjustable fields(Three (R, G, B) fields`, One On/Off switch to enable drawing or not, One field to draw a circle of adjustable radius).

Currently, all of the fields data is being read and given to proper functions.
I want my Paint Application to have an adjustable background color and make circle wherever the mouse hovers with adjustable radius and color.

But my code doesn't make a circle when mouse hovers over the image.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
def nothing(x):
    pass

colo = (0,0,255)
radius = 5

def draw_circle(event,x,y,flags,param):
    global colo,radius
    if event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        # print(str(colo) + " " + str(radius))
        cv2.circle(img,(x,y),radius,colo,-1)    

# Create a black image, a window
img = np.zeros((300,512,3), np.uint8)
cv2.namedWindow('image')
cv2.setMouseCallback('image',draw_circle)   

# create trackbars for color and radius change
cv2.createTrackbar('Red','image',0,255,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('Green','image',0,255,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('Blue','image',0,255,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('CirRadius','image',5,50,nothing)

# create switch for ON/OFF functionality
switch = '0 : OFF \n1 : ON'
cv2.createTrackbar(switch, 'image',0,1,nothing)

while(1):
    cv2.imshow('image',img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

    # get current positions of five trackbars
    r = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Red','image')
    g = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Green','image')
    b = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Blue','image')
    s = cv2.getTrackbarPos(switch,'image')
    radius = cv2.getTrackbarPos('CirRadius','image')
    colo = (b,g,r)

    if s == 0:
        img[:] = 0
    else:
        img[:] = [b,g,r]
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't tell the difference or locate the circle if color of circle and background remains same. Since you were using the `global colo` hence it was not visible.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
def nothing(x):
    pass

colo = (0,0,255)
radius = 5

def draw_circle(event,x,y,flags,param):
    global colo,radius
    if event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        # print(str(colo) + " " + str(radius))
        cv2.circle(img,(x,y),radius,(0,0,255),-1)    

# Create a black image, a window
img = np.zeros((300,512,3), np.uint8)
cv2.namedWindow('image')
cv2.setMouseCallback('image',draw_circle)   

# create trackbars for color and radius change
cv2.createTrackbar('Red','image',0,255,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('Green','image',0,255,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('Blue','image',0,255,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('CirRadius','image',5,50,nothing)

# create switch for ON/OFF functionality
switch = '0 : OFF \n1 : ON'
cv2.createTrackbar(switch, 'image',0,1,nothing)

while(1):
    cv2.imshow('image',img)
    # get current positions of five trackbars
    r = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Red','image')
    g = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Green','image')
    b = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Blue','image')
    s = cv2.getTrackbarPos(switch,'image')
    radius = cv2.getTrackbarPos('CirRadius','image')
    colo = (b,g,r)

    if s == 0:
        img[:] = 0
    else:
        img[:] = [b,g,r]

    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break


cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code.
I'm learning OpenCV now. After I referred to others' code, i use a global parameter to control brush's color.

```
pen_color = (0, 0, 0)
ix, iy = -1, -1
drawing = False


def draw_circle(event, x, y, flags, params):
    global ix, iy, pen_color, drawing
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        ix, iy = x, y
        drawing = True
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if drawing:
            cv2.circle(img, (x, y), 3, pen_color, -1)
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        drawing = False
        cv2.circle(img, (x, y), 3, pen_color, -1)


def nothing(x):
    pass


# create white img
img = np.ones((256, 512, 3), np.uint8) * 255
cv2.namedWindow('image')
cv2.setMouseCallback('image', draw_circle)

cv2.createTrackbar('Red', 'image', 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('Green', 'image', 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('Blue', 'image', 0, 255, nothing)

switch = 'switch'
cv2.createTrackbar(switch, 'image', 0, 1, nothing)

while True:
    cv2.imshow('image', img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff
    if k == ord('q'):
        break
    r = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Red', 'image')
    g = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Green', 'image')
    b = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Blue', 'image')
    s = cv2.getTrackbarPos(switch, 'image')
    if s == 1:
        pen_color = (b, g, r)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```